# How exactly do vortices generate sound and cause pressure fluctuations to produce sound waves?

Tags: waves, acoustics, vortex

I wish to understand qualitatively, how vortices generate sound by creating longitudinal sound waves? Vortices are often mentioned as the cause of sound production for things like corrugated whirly tubes, edge tones, etc. But I havent seen pictures and descriptions explaining how they cause pressure waves, what is their direction. I have no physical understanding of it and it is like throwing the word without understanding the details. First of all, how do vortices cause pressure fluctuations? In the rotating air comprising a vortex, what is pressure distribution inside it and in ambient air?
Is there a simple qualitative and visual explanation explaining the generation and propagation of sound?

Answer (score 2):

This is a non-linear process and  do not think that there is a simple explanation or theory. The starting reference is James Lighthill's [On Sound Generated Aerodynamically. I. General Theory](https://www.scirp.org/(S(351jmbntvnsjt1aadkposzje))/reference/ReferencesPapers.aspx?ReferenceID=1786789) (the link is to a recent paper citing the original)